# How can I plot a non-normalized spectrogram in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, spectrogram, denormalized

I want to plot a non-normalized spectrogram in MATLAB. my input signal  is y with 16KHz sample rate and 8bit per second. How can I plot its spectrogram in its frequency, not in normalized frequency?

Comment: multiply the normalized frequency by the Nyquist frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a license for the MATLAB signal processing toolbox, you can use the function `spectrogram`. You find details on this function on the MATLAB [help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html). The syntax is

```
S = spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,nfft,fs);
```

where `fs` is the sampling frequency. If you want to plot a spectrogram of a signal `x` with default parameters and sampling frequency 16kHz, you can just omit the other parameters:

```
spectrogram(x,[],[],[],16e3);
```

Comment: Thank you hbaderts!
I do that but don't know why the axis scaling is the half of anything I enter as FS?